# Does VirtualBox' installation warning that it will "reset your network connection" mean theirs or in general?

Tags: virtualbox, reset, network-interface

When installing VirtualBox, it presents a warning that "Installing the Oracle VM VirtualBox Networking feature will reset your network connection and temporarily disconnect you from the network."

But does this refer to **their** network cards, i.e. disconnecting **only** guest VMs, or do they mean the real network cards in the host device itself?

It didn't seem to disconnect my real cards, but I'd like to ask to be sure it's intentional.

[image: Installing VirtualBox Networking]

[image: Virtualbox reset network interfaces]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is totally intentional. It has to disable (briefly) all network interfaces in order to insert the special filter driver in the network stack that is needed to merge the VM traffic with the normal data-stream on the interface.

It is short enough that it is often not noticeable, so you may not have noticed it before, but it depends highly on what you are doing with the NIC at the time.
If you have some program running that is quite sensitive to network interruptions (like a VOIP or Skype call or, in a business environment, SAP clients) you will notice a hiccup or even a full disconnect.

Comment: Will it stop normal http/s downloads? Because it didn't. I thought even a second of interruption is enough to stop short such downloads, forcing the user to download from scratch.

Comment: @LWC Most software retries a couple of times. Especially software that connects to the internet as the internet isn’t the most reliable medium in the world anyway. The occasional packet loss does happen all the time. So to the user it looks as nothing happened, but actually the web-browser did a retry and continued without notifying the user.

Comment: in my case, I was concerned about losing the connection over Windows Remote Desktop, but it did not disconnect.